# How to add html text after a v-bind directive on a placeholder element in Vue.Js?

Tags: javascript, input, vue.js, safari, placeholder

I am using Vue.Js here. Safari is currently automatically adding "edit" as a placeholder to all input and textarea elements. I have looked online and haven't found a way to remove that "Edit" word.
So this:

```
<input autocomplete='off' type="text" ref="inputPlaceholderUser" v-bind:placeholder='user.name'>
```

is actually writing this:

**John Doeedit**
instead of just **John Doe**.

1. would you know how to remove that EDIT word? If so the next question is irrelevant
2. How should I write a javascript expression to add a space after the "user.name" so I can have at least something like **John Doe edit** instead of **John Doeedit**?

I have tried to add two different quotation marks as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions):

```
<input autocomplete='off' type="text" ref="inputPlaceholderUser" v-bind:placeholder="'user.name' + ' '">
```

but this writes:

**user.name edit**

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Safari but did you try adding an empty `placeholder`? Before the `v-bind`.

```
<input autocomplete='off' type="text" ref="inputPlaceholderUser" placeholder="" v-bind:placeholder='user.name'>
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas. Thank you for the suggestion. I have tried it but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure it's Safari that's adding the "edit" part? Of course you did try it with Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: another tip, disable javascript in safari and look at the form.